# How do I add an Outlook email signature on new Nokia 8V?

Tags: email, outlook

Recently upgraded on Verizon to the new Nokia 8V android phone.  I can't find anyway to add/change my Outlook email signature.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In the Outlook Help PDF for Windows, the path is New Email > Signature, perhaps the same mechanism? Notably, the PDF for Android-based Outlook, and iOS-based Outlook are both devoid of signature instructions. Perhaps Mobile versions don't allow it?

Answer (score 0):

To add a signature (text not html) on Outlook, simply go to Settings -> Signature.